# Target Hardware Requirements for iPhone Development

Tags: iphone

Are there limitations to doing iPhone development on an iPhone without a contract?  That is, can one purchase a used iPhone from ebay and successfully develop software for the iPhone?  Will GPS work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will work just fine in general, I've been using a first generation iphone sent from my employer in the states for months as a test and development phone without any issue.  I have been using wifi for all network related stuff and tested 3G on my own personal phone using ad hoc builds.  This phone doesn't have a valid phone contract and I just flipped it into airplane mode then turned on the wifi.

The gps appears to function fine too, I haven't done anything with gps info via the api yet, but it looks like it is pulling in the data in maps just fine.